# How to add multiple rows in same table with stored procedure in ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

These are my table designs:

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
     Member_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
     Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Phone BIGINT NOT NULL,
     Username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Toy
(
     Toy_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
     Toy_Image VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
     Toy_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Anime_Image VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
     Anime_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Toy_Distributor_Image VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
     Toy_Distributor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Price INTEGER NOT NULL,
     Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Cart
(
     Cart_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
     Toy_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
     Member_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
     Total_Quantity INTEGER,
     Total_Price INTEGER,

     CONSTRAINT FK_ToyNo
         FOREIGN KEY(Toy_No) REFERENCES Toy(Toy_No),
     CONSTRAINT FK_MemberNo
         FOREIGN KEY(Member_No) REFERENCES Member(Member_No)
)

CREATE TABLE Toy_Purchase
(
     Toy_Purchase_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
     Cart_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
     Toy_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
     Member_No UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
     Total_Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
     Total_Price INTEGER NOT NULL,
     Credit_Card_No BIGINT NOT NULL,
     Purchase_Date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT FK_CartNo
         FOREIGN KEY(Cart_No) REFERENCES Cart(Cart_No),
     CONSTRAINT FkToyNo
         FOREIGN KEY(Toy_No) REFERENCES Toy(Toy_No),
     CONSTRAINT FkMemberNo
         FOREIGN KEY(Member_No) REFERENCES Member(Member_No)
 )
```

One important thing to be noted here is that the values recorded in `Total_Quantity` and `Total_Price` of `Cart` table will be passed and inserted in `Total_Quantity` and `Total_Price` of `Toy_Purchase` table through a stored procedure called `PurchaseToys` which I will be demonstrating at the end.

This is my stored procedure called `AddToCart` where I will be selecting different toys with one or more quantity and then add to the cart.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddToCart
    @CartNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @ToyNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @MemberNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @TotalQuantity INTEGER,
    @TotalPrice INTEGER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @CartNo = NEWID()
    SET @ToyNo = (SELECT Toy_No FROM Toy)
    SET @MemberNo = (SELECT Member_No FROM Member)
    SET @TotalPrice = @TotalQuantity*(SELECT Price FROM Toy WHERE Toy_No=@ToyNo)

    INSERT INTO Cart(Cart_No, Toy_No, Member_No, Total_Quantity, Total_Price)
    VALUES(@CartNo, @ToyNo, @MemberNo, @TotalQuantity, @TotalPrice)
END
```

This is my stored procedure called `DisplayCart` which will show the list of toy items that I have added to my cart before purchasing it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DisplayCart
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Toy_Image, Toy_Name, Total_Quantity, Total_Price
    FROM 
        Toy, Cart
    WHERE 
        Toy.Toy_No = Cart.Toy_No
END
```

This is my stored procedure called `PurchaseToys`. This procedure will only be executed after I have entered my credit cart number and then clicked Confirm Payment button in the website.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurchaseToys
    @ToyPurhcaseNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @CartNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @ToyNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @MemberNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @TotalQuantity INTEGER OUTPUT,
    @TotalPrice INTEGER OUTPUT,
    @CreditCardNo BIGINT,
    @PurchaseDate DATETIME OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @ToyPurhcaseNo = NEWID()
    SET @CartNo = (SELECT Cart_No FROM Cart)
    SET @ToyNo = (SELECT Toy_No FROM Toy)
    SET @MemberNo = (SELECT Member_No FROM Member)
    SET @TotalQuantity = (SELECT Total_Quantity FROM Cart WHERE Cart_No = @CartNo) -- I'm planning to pass the value of Total_Quantity in Toy_Purchase table from Total_Quantity of Cart table
    SET @TotalPrice = (SELECT Total_Price FROM Cart WHERE Cart_No = @CartNo)  -- I'm planning to pass the value of Total_Price in Toy_Purchase table from Total_Price of Cart table
    SET @PurchaseDate = GETDATE()

    INSERT INTO Toy_Purchase (Toy_Purchase_No, Cart_No, Toy_No, Member_No, Total_Quantity, Total_Price, Credit_Card_No, Purchase_Date)
    VALUES (@ToyPurhcaseNo, @CartNo, @ToyNo, @MemberNo, @TotalQuantity, @TotalPrice, @CreditCardNo, @PurchaseDate)

    UPDATE Toy
    SET Quantity = Quantity - Total_Price 
    FROM Toy, Toy_Purchase
    WHERE Toy.Toy_No = Toy_Purchase.Toy_No
END
```

Normally if you look at the logic of this stored procedure called `PurchaseToys`, it will insert only single row in Toy_Purchase table and the `Quantity` column value of `Toy` table will be reduced for a single toy only.

However, I want to insert multiple rows into the `Toy_Purchase` table based on number of toys I have selected. For example, if I have purchased 2 different toys, the stored procedure should insert 2 rows in `Toy_Purchase` table and the `Quantity` column value in `Toy` table will be reduced for 2 different toys.

If I have purchased 4 different toys, the stored procedure should insert 4 rows into the `Toy_Purchase` table and the `Quantity` column value in Toy table will be reduced for 4 different toys.

So how do I make sure that multiple rows will be inserted in the `Toy_Purchase` table and the `Quantity` column value will be reduced for the number of different selected toys through stored procedure in ADO.NET ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling the stored procedure for each row, you have few options that you can work out.

You can use [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx) method from C# with which you can pass datatable as parameter to the table. 
If you still want to keep the stored procedure to do rest of operations at data level (you can still update the quantity column) use table valued parameters which would pass a data table as a parameter to stored procedure.

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [PurchaseToys]
     @tblPurchaseOrders Toy_Purchase READONLY AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Toy_Purchase(column1, column2, .. )
        SELECT 
            column1, column2,..  
        FROM @tblPurchaseOrders

        --Do what else you want to do here.. 
END
```

C#:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PurchaseToys"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblPurchaseOrders", dt); // dt -> data to be inserted

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Other option is to loop through each records in C# and invoke the stored procedure.